# Z3 for all variables

Tags: constraints, z3

**Context:**

In a nutshell, I'm tracking events and I represent every event with a variable (numbered, to get an order) and a value which indicates the type of event. The goal is to basically compute every possible event sequence, given a set of possible events. For example the information that I give to Z3 to represent a sequence looks similar to this:

```
RO = 1 
R1 = 4 OR 3
R2 = 3 OR 4
```

So in the end, Z3 should give me two solutions: `1,4,3` and `1,3,4`.
Given this example, I now want to add constraints to these variables
such that *every* event of type 3 must occur before type 4:

```
 for all i,j: if Ri == 4 then there exists Rj == 3 where j < i
```

That is, Z3 should **not** give me the solution `1,4,3`, but only `1,3,4`

**Problem:**

Translating this to Z3, especially the varying index which I need to map to the correct variable. Or is there a better way to do this than representing the order with explicit variables?

I know I can create constraints for every variable, e.g.

```
(R353 == 4 && (R0 == 3 || R1 == 3 || ...)) == true
```

But I'm sure there is a better way to do this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your requirements. Did you mean Z3 should give me the solution `1,3,4` after your quantified example? In any case, I'd simply put all the indices in an array, and write/generate $n+1$ constraints that says the array is always increasing/decreasing, as appropriate. In particular, I'd avoid quantifiers as much as possible. A minimal-working example of what you're trying to do can elicit better answers.

Comment: Yes 1,3,4 is the only solution because of the constraints. I guess arrays have to be initialised with a dimension (that is, the arrays are not self-expanding?). It shouldn't be a problem, since I can bound the amount of events, but anyways the generated constraints you are talking about, do they look similar to the one I proposed (except they don't use arrays?)

Comment: Arrays in Z3 (and more generally in SMT) are of infinite size and there is no initialization. How many indices there exist depends on the sort (type) of the index, i.e. a Boolean index variable implicitly means the array can only hold two elements.

Comment: As Christopher mentioned, you'd need to explicitly track of lower-upper bounds. Should be easy in your case since you know how many elements there are. I'm thinking two parallel arrays, one contains the elements, other indirectly indexed from the first. The constraints would say the second one is totally ordered; should be simpler than yours. (No quantifiers should be needed.) But, it's really hard to speak in the abstract! A simple example showing the encoding would go a long way! (And is the preferred way of asking questions in SO.)